# SOFU definition of "Troll"

Tags: support

Under the "no stupid questions, just stupid answers" theory, what's the definition of Troll as applicable to SOFU?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**troll**, *n.*

1. One who posts questions, answers, or comments intended purely to prompt knee-jerk reactions from others or garner attention for themselves (no actual desire to obtain or share programming knowledge).
2. Your mama.

Comment: I thought it's "yo mama", but then again, I don't speak jive

Comment: I was expecting an urban dictionary style definition for the first answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I take offense to that. I am not a troll.

Comment: From Detroit, I learned it as "jo mama"

Answer (score 7):

Does this cover The "Accidental Trolls"?  It happens...

- **User A:** *"Just use language **Y**'s **aaaa**-ability!"*
- **User B:** *"But, language **X** does not have proper **aaaa**-ability, unlike language **Y**"*
- **User A:** *"Why do you hate language **X**???"* (Heating up...)
- **User B:** *"I don't, it is just that language **X** is a **iiiii** language, and language **Y** is very **jjjjj**"*
- **Troll A:** *"Arghhhhhh!  You are so evil, troll!!! I'm going to complain on MSO"*

...or...

- **User OP:** *"{huge-unformatted-stack-trace}"*
- **User B:** comments *"Unless you give us code and a narrative, we can't help you"*.  Three subsequent down votes.
- **User C:** comments *"Why all the down votes?  SO is so mean for newbies"*
- **User D:** {formats stack-trace}
- **User OP:** answers *"tx.  {another-huge-stack-trace}"*
- **Users *:** down votes for question and answer of OP, question closed
- **User C:** *"SO is so uncool for new people...too many trolls"*
- **User C:** goes to MSO, cites unreferenced example of how mean SOpedias are to newbies
- **MSOpedias**:  figure out what thread it was, deem it justified

I get confused who the trolls are...

Comment: The invariant for this discussion is "C != D" :)

Comment: IMHO, troll implies intent. You don't *accidentally* troll (though a troll may not identify themselves as a troll).

Comment: I like the SOpedias term! Did you just invent it, or where did you get it from?

Comment: I invented it and claim elusive copyright!  I think.  Well, just promise to buy me a beer some day and you can use it :P

Comment: @Shog9 & @PonyMaster: Um, ok.  Where do I fit into this hierarchy?  I wanna be labeled too!  Something I can get offended about, and down vote you both until the troll-catcher kicks in.  Please.

Comment: @Mehrdad: User D is only concerned about a S&W badge.  Probably doesn't even know the language in question.

Comment: @Stu: i think what you've identified is that troll is a pejorative term, and often used as an insult in situations where it does not apply (or applies *to the person using it* even...). Spam / spammer / spamming are used similarly: "Joe keeps trolling the site with his VB spam", "Sal will never stop spamming the site with homework questions. What a troll.", etc.

Answer (score 6):

I think @Shog9's answer covers a core definition, but I think a troll on S[OFU] can be anyone observed as engaging in the following behaviors:

1. Posting LMGTFY links (this is my new pet peeve)
2. People who constantly open polls/etc. which should be wiki, solely for the purpose of rep-mining. (Polls used to be acceptable, to an extent, but when all one user does is open and/or contribute to them ... )
3. People who engage in petty personal battles on the site
4. Those who ask the same question over and over again because the first *x* times were closed as duplicate
5. Spammers

There are probably about a gazillion more, but that's a decent start for me.

Comment: trolling == abuse but abuse != trolling

Comment: But == is commutative. More like "class troll : public abuse"

Comment: Troll is implemented in C++ and screwed up the operator overloading...

Comment: LMGTFY? What does that mean?

Comment: @Michael: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=LMGTFY

Comment: That's hilarious. Thank you.

Answer (score -7):

One who thinks that randomizing the order of answers with the same score is a good idea.

Alternatively, one who doesn't like waffles.  If you don't like waffles, this site can't help you, and you can't help this site.  Go away you troll.

Comment: (-1) Someone who puts answers to bait other users is a troll. Right now, that's you.

Comment: Yes, this is a troll.  Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @belgariontheking - There appears to be a fish on your line.

Comment: Alright, let me rephrase then. Kidding or not, being a jackass is unacceptable in my book.

Comment: *hands devinb a plate of waffles*

Comment: Appreciated.

Comment: @Shog9 - You just had to didn't you?

Comment: Is there any problem that waffles can't solve?

Comment: Not if properly made with good yeast and drenched in real butter and maple syrup... A truly wondrous food, waffles.

Comment: What -  no ice cream?